# Python igrap create manual graph

Tags: python

im am new at Python/igraph and want to draw manual a network.

---

```
from igraph import *

g = Graph(directed = True)

#now create simple directed graph

Tomas -> Dennis, Dennis -> Hans, Hans -> Tomas, Dennis -> Bert

g.vs["name"] = ["Tomas", "Dennis", "Hans", "Tomas", "Bert"]

layout = g.layout_kamada_kawai()

g.vs["label"] = g.vs["name"]

layout = g.layout("kamada_kawai")

plot(g, layout=layout)
```

---

Is it posible to make label on on connections.( The undirected/directed lanes)

Comment: According to the igraph documentation - you can change the colour and width (and other attributes such as angle, arrows etc) of edges when you plot them - but you can't label them : http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html - section on layout and plotting.

Comment: Thx for the answer,

do you know some link where more dokumetion for analysis with Igraph.
I cant find any where or its got a page but with out information.

Comment: What do you mean "analysis". Are you talking about things like average distances, link counts etc ?

Comment: its like degree and betweenes at dokumetion but its must exist more as the two funktion to analysis of network.
For exeple: Network strength and clustering. I searching already 3 days for dokumetion of all funktion from Igraph.

Comment: The full documentation is here : http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph-module.html - I would imagine what you are looking for will be part of the Graph class (if it exists at all) - try : http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html - that seems to have a lot of analysis functions - I don't understand any of them though - Graph theory is not my thing.

Comment: thx that was one of the thing i lookingfor :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
from igraph import *

g = Graph(directed = True)
g.add_vertices(5)
g.add_edges([(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(1,4)])

g.vs["name"] = ["Tomas", "Dennis", "Hans", "Tomas_2", "Bert"]
g.vs["label"] = g.vs["name"]

#Next I count the number of edges and I give numbers as names

g.es["name"] = range(g.ecount())
g.es["label"] = g.es["name"]

plot(g)
```

You should get something like the following:

[image: Fig]